# How to convert a string type into ostringstream

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I have the following code, I want to convert the str string type into ostringstream so i can use .rdbuf()

```
            CTime tm;
            tm=CTime::GetCurrentTime();
            CString str=tm.Format("%X");
```

Comment: Why not put that string *into* the `ostringstream` instead of converting it into one? Hint: Streams are writeable. Write to it.

Comment: Hi,   That is what i did, correct me if i am wrong: ostringstream os2; then I added os2 << str;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the constructor

```
std::ostringstream os2(str);
```

Also, if you already construct the `ostringstream` object, then the `<<` operator will work.